# DNS lookup not working in a VM until I run dhclient

Tags: networking, server, dns, virtualization, dhcp

Have already spent 4 hours trying to debug why DNS lookups do not work when the VM boots up.

Not only did I try to debug the problem manually, but went over hundreds of articles on the internet, including the solutions posted on Ask Ubuntu which by the way none worked.

I'm trying to build a VM template (Ubuntu Server 22.04) that I can easily clone inside VMware if I want a clean instance up and running.

DNS lookups start working when I run `dhclient` but I don't wanna have that autostart on every boot, the configuration file should automatically pinpoint to the DNS server to be used instead of automagically configuring through `dhclient`.

If using `dhclient` is necessary than it defeats the purpose of the "manual configuration" in the first place.

I should also point out that I've done some preconfigurations in the `/etc/systemd/network` directory correlating to the *NAT*, *Host-Only* and *Bridge* interfaces provided by VMware.

```bash
# cd /etc/systemd/network
# cat 001-nat.network
[Match]
Name=ens32

[Network]
Gateway=192.168.33.1
DNS=192.168.33.1
DHCP=yes

# cat 002-host-only.network
[Match]
Name=ens34

[Network]
Gateway=10.0.10.1
DHCP=yes

# cat 003-bridge.network
[Match]
Name=ens35

[Network]
Gateway=192.168.88.1
DHCP=yes
```

The reason I did this was because in the future I'd want VMs with static IP addresses and this is the way I know of setting it up.

Here is the output of `ifconfig`, `ip`, `route`, `resolvectl` and `ping` before and after running `dhclient`:

- `ifconfig`

```
# =============== BEFORE ===============
ens32: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.33.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.33.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feaa:6533  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:aa:65:33  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4  bytes 808 (808.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12  bytes 1474 (1.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens34: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.10.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.10.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feaa:653d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:aa:65:3d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 151  bytes 13923 (13.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 164  bytes 17651 (17.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens35: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.88.242  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.88.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feaa:6547  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:aa:65:47  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 49  bytes 4098 (4.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 35  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20  bytes 2038 (2.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

# =============== AFTER ===============
ens32: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.33.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.33.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feaa:6533  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:aa:65:33  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9  bytes 1958 (1.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15  bytes 2500 (2.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens34: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.10.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.10.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feaa:653d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:aa:65:3d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 206  bytes 18791 (18.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 202  bytes 23949 (23.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens35: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.88.242  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.88.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:feaa:6547  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:aa:65:47  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 77  bytes 6471 (6.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 53  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26  bytes 2738 (2.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

- `ip route show`

```
# =============== BEFORE ===============
default via 10.0.10.1 dev ens34 proto static onlink
default via 192.168.33.1 dev ens32 proto static onlink
default via 192.168.88.1 dev ens35 proto static onlink
default via 192.168.33.1 dev ens32 proto dhcp src 192.168.33.4 metric 1024
default via 192.168.88.1 dev ens35 proto dhcp src 192.168.88.242 metric 1024
1.0.0.1 via 192.168.88.1 dev ens35 proto dhcp src 192.168.88.242 metric 1024
1.1.1.1 via 192.168.88.1 dev ens35 proto dhcp src 192.168.88.242 metric 1024
10.0.10.0/24 dev ens34 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.10.6 metric 1024
10.0.10.1 dev ens34 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.10.6 metric 1024
192.168.33.0/24 dev ens32 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.33.4 metric 1024
192.168.33.1 dev ens32 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.33.4 metric 1024
192.168.88.0/24 dev ens35 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.88.242 metric 1024
192.168.88.1 dev ens35 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.88.242 metric 1024

# =============== AFTER ===============
default via 192.168.88.1 dev ens35 proto static onlink
default via 192.168.88.1 dev ens35 proto dhcp src 192.168.88.242 metric 1024
1.0.0.1 via 192.168.88.1 dev ens35 proto dhcp src 192.168.88.242 metric 1024
1.1.1.1 via 192.168.88.1 dev ens35 proto dhcp src 192.168.88.242 metric 1024
10.0.10.0/24 dev ens34 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.10.6
192.168.33.0/24 dev ens32 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.33.4
192.168.88.0/24 dev ens35 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.88.242 metric 1024
192.168.88.1 dev ens35 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.88.242 metric 1024
```

- `route -n`

```
# =============== BEFORE ===============
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.10.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens34
0.0.0.0         192.168.33.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens32
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens35
0.0.0.0         192.168.33.1    0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 ens32
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 ens35
1.0.0.1         192.168.88.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   1024   0        0 ens35
1.1.1.1         192.168.88.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   1024   0        0 ens35
10.0.10.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1024   0        0 ens34
10.0.10.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 ens34
192.168.33.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1024   0        0 ens32
192.168.33.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 ens32
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1024   0        0 ens35
192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 ens35

# =============== AFTER ===============
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens35
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 ens35
1.0.0.1         192.168.88.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   1024   0        0 ens35
1.1.1.1         192.168.88.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   1024   0        0 ens35
10.0.10.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens34
192.168.33.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens32
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1024   0        0 ens35
192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 ens35
```

- `resolvectl status`

```
# =============== BEFORE ===============
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
       DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        DNS Domain: localdomain

Link 2 (ens32)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 192.168.33.1
    DNS Domain: localdomain

Link 3 (ens34)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 10.0.10.1
    DNS Domain: localdomain

Link 4 (ens35)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1

# =============== AFTER ===============
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: 1.1.1.1
       DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        DNS Domain: localdomain

Link 2 (ens32)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 192.168.33.1
    DNS Domain: localdomain

Link 3 (ens34)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 10.0.10.1
    DNS Domain: localdomain

Link 4 (ens35)
Current Scopes: DNS
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1
```

- `ping -c 8 google.com`

```
# =============== BEFORE ===============
PING google.com (142.250.180.206) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- google.com ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7174ms

# =============== AFTER ===============
PING google.com (142.250.180.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bud02s33-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.180.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=20.7 ms
64 bytes from bud02s33-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.180.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=20.7 ms
64 bytes from bud02s33-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.180.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=20.4 ms
64 bytes from bud02s33-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.180.206): icmp_seq=4 ttl=116 time=21.0 ms
64 bytes from bud02s33-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.180.206): icmp_seq=5 ttl=116 time=26.2 ms
64 bytes from bud02s33-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.180.206): icmp_seq=6 ttl=116 time=20.7 ms
64 bytes from bud02s33-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.180.206): icmp_seq=7 ttl=116 time=20.8 ms
64 bytes from bud02s33-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.180.206): icmp_seq=8 ttl=116 time=22.2 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7012ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.400/21.588/26.168/1.806 ms
```

VMware NAT Configuration:

[image]

I am new to Linux, so I apologize if I'm missing out on some important detail in the configuration. This isn't the first time I encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue through [netplan](https://netplan.io/).

Here are my configurations for future reference:

**/etc/netplan/001-nat.yaml**

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens32:
      # //
      # // Set both DHCP options to false
      # // when using a static IP
      # //
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      # //
      # // Here you put your static IP
      # //
      #addresses:
      #  - 192.168.33.X/prefix
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.33.1]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.33.1
```

**/etc/netplan/002-host-only.yaml**

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      # //
      # // Set both DHCP options to false
      # // when using a static IP
      # //
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      # //
      # // Here you put your static IP
      # //
      #addresses:
      #  - 10.0.10.X/prefix
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.0.10.1]
```

**/etc/netplan/003-bridge.yaml**

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens34:
      # //
      # // Set both DHCP options to false
      # // when using a static IP
      # //
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      # //
      # // Here you put your static IP
      # //
      #addresses:
      #  - 192.168.88.X/prefix
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.88.1]
```